# Debug steps jumps in reverse order

Tags: c, visual-c++

Hello I have several lines of code in my `C` projects related to LVGL that runs in Visual Studio 2019.

```
116    lv_coord_t  w=lv_table_get_col_width(table, 0);
117    printf("w=%d",w);
118    lv_table_set_col_width(table, 0, w*2);
```

Got strange debud steps sequence by lines: `116, 117, 116, 117, 118`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was expecting sequence: `116, 117, 118`

Why I get this strange behavior?

Comment: It's common for an optimizing compiler to rearrange and interleave instructions pertaining to different source lines.  So maybe some instruction relevant to line 116 has been moved after the code for line 117.  The compiler marks it as still being part of line 116, so when you trap on that instruction, the debugger shows you line 116.  This is a normal occurrence when debugging optimized code.  To confirm this, we'd need a complete MRE and the exact compilation and optimization options being used.

Answer (score 1):

It completely depends on where you have put these 3 lines of code.

It seems that they are put in rendering loop callback function or something similar that get executed by threads. which explain execution pointer jumping back and forward.

you can avoid these behavior by other techniques like printing variables and thread number# or follow instruction provided by Microsoft for debugging multithreaded apps [Debug the multithreaded app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/get-started-debugging-multithreaded-apps?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I don't know about Visual Studio, but most debuggers when single-stepping would trace just one thread at a time.  So I wouldn't expect to see the debugger spontaneously switch between threads each time you step.

Comment: But with respect to your reputation I have seen similar manner in different IDEs like QtCreator and Intellij Idea including MSVC. And it is very common and expected behavior. Thats why we have parallel watch and parallel stack in visual studio debug windows. see [Learn to Debug multithreaded application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/get-started-debugging-multithreaded-apps?view=vs-2019#ParallelStacks)